# Umbraco CMS can you store views in a Database?

Tags: c#, umbraco, umbraco7

I'd like to install umbraco in a way that will allow multiple instances to be deployed, but to share media and views between them (think "load balancing").

The default installation appears to place media and views in subdirectories of the installed Umbraco instance. For media, it would appear that the data can be moved to a central location using either S3, Azure Blob storage, or custom IFileSystem providers.

It is not clear to me whether the same can be done with Views.

**Is it possible to redirect storage of views to a virtual file system? If so, how would this be accomplished.**

(I don't need code, just to know what classes/configuration is needed, I'm specifically using Umbraco CMS 7.x, if this is behavior has changed since previous versions.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

If you are even just thinking about load balancing then make sure to [follow this exact documentation](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Installation/load-balancing), there is currently no other way of load balancing Umbraco reliably.

Answer (score 2):

Also, to add to Sebastian's answer... the general way to achieve what you want is to turn on file replcation between the load-balanced servers.

Comment: I am not sure this is a good idea, lucene.net is one of the major factors, and I know from experience that it has a very specific/picky file structure. I think that files getting replicated in a non-atomic way (especially with multiple writers) would lead to a very nasty set of bugs (just as one example).

Comment: File replication forms part of the recomended approach.  It is working for us.  See this article - https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Installation/load-balancing